# Optimize MIN & MAX query

Tags: mysql, indexing, max, query-optimization, min

My database table consists of more than 10 million records. I am writing a query containing MIN and MAX functions on the created_date column which I already indexed. But when I am running my select statement it takes too much time and some times execution time get over and do not receive any output.

Is there any way to optimize my query. The query I am trying is below.

```
SELECT MIN(created_date) AS Min, MAX(created_date) as Max FROM network ORDER
BY id DESC LIMIT 1000000
```

The above query will give you `MIN AND MAX,created_date` from the last latest 1 000 000 rows.

Comment: The above query will not give you min and max values for the latest 1000000. The ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses are applied AFTER the aggregation takes place and are therefore redundant.

Comment: @Strawberry can you write down optimise query for this

Comment: For what? The max and min values for the latest 1000000 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(created_date) AS Min,
       MAX(created_date) AS Max   -- Get min and max from the 1M rows
    FROM (
        SELECT created_date
            FROM network
            ORDER BY created_date desc
            LIMIT 1000000
         ) AS recent          -- Collect the latest 1M rows
```

This index would help *some*:

```
INDEX(created_date)
```

**Rereading question**

The latest date is simply `MAX(created_date)`.  The millionth date is `( SELECT created_date FROM network ORDER BY created_date DESC LIMIT 1000000, 1 )

So, this is the first choice:

```
SELECT ( SELECT created_date FROM network
            ORDER BY created_date DESC LIMIT 1000000, 1 ) AS Min,
       MAX(created_date) AS Max
    FROM network;
```

**Summary Table**

```
CREATE TABLE Dates (
    create_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    ct INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ct)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Then, every hour (or other unit of time), count the number of records and store it there.

To find `MIN(created_date)` is a bit messy; it means summing through that table to find when the count adds up to about 1M, and declaring the hour (or whatever) is when it happened.

Alternatively (and probably better) is to capture the exact `DATETIME` of each 1000th row.  This means probing `network` frequently, and storing just the `created_date` (drop the `ct` column).  Then this finds the *approximate* time of the 1M ago:

```
SELECT created_date
    FROM Dates
    ORDER BY created_date DESC
    LIMIT 1000, 1
```

(And use that as the subquery for Min.)

Comment: Thanks Rick. But my requirement is to get result within 0-5 seconds. currently its takes nearly 13-20 seconds with your posted query

Comment: If the 1M does not have to be exactly that value, I can suggest a way with summary tables that will probably be sub-second.

Comment: Your suggestion are welcome. Please let me explain about summary tables

Comment: 3 more suggestions